# How to save the time of execution of a particular transaction ?

Tags: sql-server

iam trying to execute some T-SQL comands in a build a database project. One of them is to save the time of the 7th transaction and latter on to realize a Recovery of the database in the point-of-time of the 7th transaction. Till now i have done a data backup and a log backup and the required transactions except the 7th :). Can anyone help me?

Comment: Your question is not at all clear. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Iam explaining. I created a simple database, with all the tables required. I was asked to execute 10 query (update, insert, delete and create additional tables), for the 7th i have to save its time of execution. This time  of execution i have to use it latter to complete a Recovery in this point-of time.

Comment: There is something getting lost in translation or not being communicated here. If you want to restore to the point of running the 7th query why not just stop after running the 7th query and not run the last 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this

```
declare @starttime datetime
declare @endtime datetime
set @starttime =getdate()   

 -- execute your query here

set @endtime = GETDATE()
select @endtime-@starttime AS ExcTime
```

Comment: Yes sure, and about life, life was created for you, not you for the life. An application from the Bible.